# spring security and ldap, group-search-filter

Tags: spring-security-ldap

hi im implementing j2ee with spring security and ldap.

here is my ldap structure:

```
DIT
 |
 |--Root DSE
        |
        |--dc=apacheLDAP
        |         |
        |         |--ou=roles
        |         |     |
        |         |     |--role=1
        |         |     |--role=2
        |         |     |--role=3   
        |         |
        |         |--ou=users
        |         |     |
        |         |     |--user=ali
        |         |     |--user=john
        |         |     |--user=bettyboop
        |
        |--ou=system
               |
               |uid=admin
```

here is the content of my spring security:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:ldap-authentication-provider
     user-search-filter="uid={0}"
     user-search-base="ou=user,dc=apacheLDAP"
     group-search-filter="description={0}"
     group-search-base="ou=roles,dc=apacheLDAP"
     group-role-attribute="role"
     role-prefix="ROLE_"
  />
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server url="ldap://192.168.1.100:10389"
     manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system"
     manager-password="secret"
/>
```

for each role i have a description attribute which has a value of the user-search-filter. so if user ali logs in, the user-search-filter will be uid=ali,ou=users,dc=apacheLDAP. this value will be searched into the role's description attribute. this works fine.

however, i will need to modify the schema by inserting a role attribute into user schema. so the checking of a user role is done in the use schema instead. for example, if ali has role 1 and role 2, his user schema will look like this:

```
uid    |   ali
role   |   1
role   |   2
```

how should i modify spring-security so that checking of authorizaton is done in user schema instead of role schema?

Comment: Did you find out any solution for this? I am looking for the same thing too. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, i used spring ldap template which binds to ldap and retrieve information from user, roles and etc. Then in java i created a internal map to store their relationship. With this map i was able to check user authorization. It was alot more work.

Comment: Oh one thing to note. Avoid binding to ldap frequently. For example, if ur doing a web app, store the authorization map in a session. This is because, ldap may crash if theres too many binding

Comment: What container/application server are you using? I'm using JBoss. Thank you